# nextron don't recognize less file in node_modules

Tags: webpack, next.js, less, node-modules

nextron project don't recognize less file in node_modules

[image]

```
../node_modules/.store/antd@4.24.10/node_modules/antd/es/affix/style/index.less
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)


index.js?e493:594 Uncaught ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.

@root-entry-name: default;
| 
| @import './index-pure.less';
```

demo project in there:
https://codesandbox.io/s/fv7cod

---

I also tried add `next.config.js` in the root directory but don't work.

```
const withLess = require('@zeit/next-less');

module.exports = withLess({
  lessLoaderOptions: {
    javascriptEnabled: true,
  },
  webpack(config, options) {

    // custom webpack config
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.less$/,
      loader: 'less-loader',
      options: {
        lessOptions: {
          strictMath: true,
        }
      }
    },
    {
      test: /antd.*\.less$/,
      use: ["style-loader", {loader: 'css-loader', options: {sourceMap: 1}}, "postcss-loader", "less-loader"]
    },
    )

    return config;
  }
});
```